# Isolate an IF statement?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, if-statement

I would like to make sure that the "||" statement block is not applicable for this if statement :

```
if exist "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\%Desktop%\filename*.doc" (
ren "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\%Desktop%\filename*.doc" "newname*.doc"
)
```

Is there a way to isolate it from the rest of the code without having to interfere with the "||" statement block and without having to add a 2nd "||" statement block ?

I tried to add the if statement right after :

```
) || (
echo       Access refused ^(check permissions^)
)
```

But it executes the "||" statement block if any error occurs. Same thing if I remove the IF statement and leave the REN command only.

Here is the whole code :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set BackupDest=D:\backup

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%HomeDrive%\users\*" ^| findstr /x /i /l /v /g:"%~dp0exclude_users.txt"') do if exist "%BackupDest%\%%I\" (

    echo -----------------------------------------
    echo      Processing user : %%I
    echo -----------------------------------------
    echo

    :: checking write permissions
    copy /y nul "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable" >nul 2>&1 &&
    (
        del "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable"

        xcopy "%%I\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Desktop\" /e /i /y
        xcopy "%%I\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Documents\" /e /i /y

        :: renaming some files
        if exist "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\%Desktop%\filename*.doc" (
            ren "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\%Desktop%\filename*.doc" "newname*.doc"
        )

    ) || (
        echo       Access refused ^(check permissions^)
    )
)

pause
exit
```

Any help would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added indentations to your code, in order that it highlights your errors more clearly to readers. You can begin by getting rid of your broken labels, `:: checking write permissions` and `:: renaming some files`, using the correct syntax for a remark, `Rem checking write permissions` and `Rem renaming some files`. You should also move your lonely opening parenthesis up onto the previous line, i.e. `&& (`. Also you do not have to escape opening parentheses within your parenthesised blocks, just closing ones!

Comment: The `command1 && command2 || command3` construct is often misinterpreted, since people often think the result of `command1` is checked by both `&&` and `||`, but that is not true; what happens is the following: if `command1` fails (that is, its exit code is not zero), `command2` does not execute, but `command3` does; if `command1` succeeds (so its exit code is zero), `command2` executes; now it is the exit code of `command2` that determines what `||` does! Or, in other words, you have to read the complete command line/block from left to write and to regard every executed command...

Comment: ...With that said, let me recommend to use something like `command1 & if not ErrorLevel 1 (command2) else (command1)`, because this actually checks the `ErrorLevel` returned by `command1`; note that `if ErrorLevel 1` actually means if `ErrorLevel` is *greater than or equal to* `1`...